# What is the difference between MIPS and Execution time

Tags: performance, cpu

When it comes to rating the performance of a processor, is calculating the Million Instructions Per Second (MIPS) a practical measure to use? 
Or is finding the Execution Time (IC x CPI x 1/CR) the main thing to use?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have one CPU that does 100 million tiny little instructions that don't do much on their own per second. Next; imagine you have another CPU where you need a quarter of the instructions to do the same work; which can do 50 million larger instructions per second. The second CPU has half as many MIPs but is twice as fast.

Now.. Imagine you have 2 CPUs that both execute the exact same instructions; where one CPU runs at 1 GHz, can do 5 instructions per cycle, and stalls rarely; and the other CPU runs at 4 GHz, can only do 2 instructions per cycle, and spends a lot more time stalled doing nothing (due to cache misses, branch mispredictions, etc). In this case the 1 GHz CPU might be significantly faster than the 4 GHz CPU.

Finally; imagine you have 2 CPUs that both execute the exact same instructions, both have exactly the same clock frequency, both execute the same number of instructions per cycle, and both spend exactly the same amount of time stalled. One CPU has overheats easily and had to "under-clock" itself to a crawl after 250 milliseconds of not being idle just to avoid melting itself, and the other CPU can go at max. speed continuously without ever overheating.

Execution time is how long it takes to do some work taking everything into account (and can be extremely different for different types of work); while MIPS is like a real estate agent determining how much a building is worth by measuring the weight of a rubber chicken.

Comment: LOL that's a very comparison in the end.. thank you for the detailed response

Comment: This answer has been linked in my uni's parallel computing course HAHA!!!